# pass Imagick output to another function with Imagick (no saving)

Tags: php, imagick

I have two function in two separate class, both have some Imagick processing.
I want the first Imagick to resize image and then send it to another Imagick instance without saving it as a file.

In the first class crop

```
         function cropimage($inputfile){
          $image = new Imagick($inputfile);
          $image->cropimage($w, $h, $x, $y);
          # and here I wish to return some $image->output???() which let me to use it in second class
         return ????;
         }
```

And in second class resize

```
     function resizeImage(){
      $crop = new crop(); // my first class instance
      $image_to_work = $crop->cropimage($this->image); // output from first class
      $image = new Imagick($image_to_work);

      $image->resizeImage($width, $height);
      $image->writeImage($outputfile);
     }
```

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Images can be passed around as variables:

```
function cropimage($inputfile) {
   $image = new Imagick($inputfile);
   $image->cropimage($w, $h, $x, $y);

   return $image;
}

function resizeImageAndSave($image) {
      $image->resizeImage($width, $height);
      $image->writeImage($outputfile);
}

$image = cropimage("./test.png"); // return the image
resizeImageAndSave($image); // pass it into the next function
```

Comment: Please update your question , rather than using comments, as code is not readable in them.

Answer (score -2):

Use sessions.

First, make sure you have `session_start()` in every script that will utilize sessions.

Then do something like `$_SESSION['image'] = $image` and then your next script can access that session variable.

Comment: This is terrible advice, do not do this ever